# text with redundant side chars formatting in emacs

Tags: text, emacs, formatting

I did lots of search without luck. I think even this is easy but it could help, so here it goes.

Here the goal is to format a kind of Java String to plain text.

For example, consider a String in java code, 

   `logger.LogText( "Hi, this is 1st line " + "\n" + 

                                    "speak sth. in 2nd line " + "\n" + 

                                   "answered...? ");` 



and i want to copy from the whole String and paste to my plain text file, then run 
 
    `M-x some-format-function-by-template-on-selection`

and i got a result 

`Hi, this is 1st line 

speak sth. in 2nd line 
 
answered...?` 


Is there a built-in command for this? 
It's not have to use template, but don't you think it's cool?
Currently i try to use 'align' to work around.

Comment: As `(forward-sexp)` treats a double-quoted string (and `\"` as an escaped quote mark within the string) as a balanced expression, and Emacs strings understand `\n` as well, another approach for implementing a function would be to skip forward over each string, remove the `+` symbols, and use the remainder as the arguments to `(concat)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The built-in commands are the regexp functions :-)

```
(defun my-reduce-to-string (start end)
  "Extract a quoted string from the selected region."
  (interactive "r")
  (let* ((text1 (replace-regexp-in-string ".*?\"\\([^\"]+\\)\"[^\"]*" "\\1" 
                    (buffer-substring start end)))
         (text (replace-regexp-in-string "\\\\n" "\n" text1)))
     (delete-region start end)
     (insert text)))
```

Note that this is a *destructive* function -- it replaces the text in the buffer as requested.